# Gnome Shell Integration in Chrome not working

Tags: chrome, gnome-shell

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, which seems to also make a full reinstall of Chromium (as all my plugins were removed).

Now, trying to access `https://extensions.gnome.org/` to enable Gnome Shell extensions, but the message:

> We cannot detect a running copy of GNOME on this system, so some parts of the interface may be disabled. See our [troubleshooting](https://extensions.gnome.org/about/#no-detection) entry for more information.

keeps appearing. There is nothing in my `chrome://plugins` page, but the site still seems to be whitelisted in my "click to play" settings. Has anyone found out how to force `Chrome` to get this plugin?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but I just had this problem. An easy workaround for me was to use Firefox instead.

Comment: Yeah Firefox works for me as well, I just want to know why it doesn't in Chrome anymore.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Chrome and Chromium dropped support for the NPAPI plugins (Netscape Plugin Application Programming Interface) in favor of PPAPI (Pepper Plugin Application Programming Interface) so all plugins that use NPAPI (like GNOME Extension plugin) are just not supported.

The only alternative is using another browser that allows them (like Firefox) or asking the developers to move to PPAPI (unlikely).

**NOTE:** This is the blog post from the Chromium blog mentioning this, titled: [Saying Goodbye to Our Old Friend NPAPI](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html).

Comment: I just stumbled into this today, I'm an avid chrome user, this is total BS. Any info on why the drop?

Comment: More info on this: http://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/1wvv60/extensions_cannot_be_installed_from/

Comment: As a work around there's this scripting solutiont to re-enable your extensions after a crash/update: http://askubuntu.com/questions/359958/extensions-are-turned-off-after-reboot

Comment: @slm there has been angry users in all bug trackers, but [this is the main one](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=727936)

Comment: Unconfirmed (as of now) [bug report for chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=382835)

Answer (score 11):

You want to install the "`chrome-gnome-shell`" (and probably also the ["GNOME Shell Integration" Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep/))

You can find instructions to install `chrome-gnome-shell` for your distro [here on the GNOME wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation).

---

Essentially, install for your distro:

- Ubuntu - available from [ppa:ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell](https://launchpad.net/~ne0sight/+archive/ubuntu/chrome-gnome-shell).
- Fedora - available from [region51/chrome-gnome-shell](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/region51/chrome-gnome-shell) copr.
- Gentoo - [Ebuild is available in the main tree](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation).
- Arch - available in the AUR: [chrome-gnome-shell](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chrome-gnome-shell-git/).
- [Other](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation)

And then add the [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep/).

Comment: This solved it for me.

Comment: Debian testing July 2018 - nope, doesn't work. It doesn't think the chrome-gnome-shell is installed.

Comment: Yes. For Ubuntu 18.04, I had to do both `sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell` and click on the `Add to Chrome` button in [GNOME Shell integration](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep) to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because the plugin package was not installed. Installing it with Yum immediately fixed the problem, although you have to use Firefox because Chrome doesn't support the protocol they are using.

```
sudo yum install gnome-shell-browser-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [chrome-gnome-shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) depending on your distro and for the first time execute:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/chrome-gnome-shell --gapplication-service
```

After this the addon from chrome will detect the native plugin.

Answer (score -3):

Try going to chrome://flags/ and enabling Npapi

Comment: This is **impossible** to do.  It's been completely ripped out of the code base on Linux.